# GEDCOM compatible file output in C#.NET

Tags: file-format, family-tree, gedcom

I tried to create a simple interface for building a [gedcom](https://www.gedcom.org/) compatible text file using C#.NET.

I am stuck with proper FAM record creation (I mean, something is logically wrong in my code). I believe that [tester.cs](https://github.com/anytizer/gedcomer/blob/master/exe/tester.cs) has a complete information of grandfather, father, self, spouse, child1, and grandson relationships.

Is is possible to correct the gedcom output, without making significant changes in the tester.cs?
May be you need to [fork the entire source code](https://github.com/anytizer/gedcomer). The software produces **gedcom.ged** file, which should be loaded in [Simple Family Tree 1.32](http://www.jdmcox.com/) to see that the gedcom is valid.

Currently, I ended up with the funny and unusual relationships as in the picture.

[image]

Grandfather should have married to grandmother, and "self" needs to have a child, giving a grand child to grand father. Gotra's spouse should be null (unmentioned). And like that...

Probably I should fix something in [individual.cs](https://github.com/anytizer/gedcomer/blob/master/classes/individual.cs).

Your help is kindly expected. PS: I am also working to resolve the issue, and the source code may change a bit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the Individual and Family classes represent the INDI and FAM gedcom records?

Comment: Tip: create the test family tree in Simple Family Tree and take a look at the exported gedcom file.

Comment: Yes. individual.cs produces INDI individuals properly. But the relationships are somehow messed while creating FAM records.

Comment: The gedcom INDI record has FAMC and FAMS relationships to FAM records. The FAM record has HUSB, WIFE and CHIL relationships to INDI records. This doesn't correspond to father, mother, spouses, children and belongsToFamily relationships of an individual. An individual can be a husband/wife of family A and B and a child of family C. Father, mother and their children are one family.